# ACF Field value in wordpress login message filter

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add a custom message after the WordPress logo on the WordPress login form, I am using the ACF field on the home page to echo the value on the WordPress login page, I have mentioned the code, any help?

```
function alltomhobby_login_message( $message ) {
    if ( empty($message) ){
        $logintext = the_field('login_text');
        return $logintext;
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_message', 'alltomhobby_login_message' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) echoes out the result. You want [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead.

However these won't automatically default to reading fields from the home page. You're going to have to give `get_field` the post ID of the home page to look up so it knows where to get the field from. Something like:

```php
function alltomhobby_login_message( $message ) {
    if ( empty( $message ) ){
        $show_on_front = get_option( 'show_on_front' );
        $home_page_id = ( 'page' === $show_on_front )
                            ? (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' )
                            : ( ( 'post' === $show_on_front )
                                     ? (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) : NULL );

        if ( isset( $home_page_id ) ) {
            $logintext = get_field( 'login_text', $home_page_id );
            return $logintext;
        }
    }

    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'login_message', 'alltomhobby_login_message' );
```

Or you could instead hard-code the page ID if you know it and it's fixed.

Comment: Your code and using hardcoded page id works perfectly, thank you.